# mongoengine - Do i need to create form for a model ? How to validate ListField(ImageField()) either by form or directly

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

i am using mongodb for django using mongoengine .
Usually for normal models, we write forms and the after submisson of the input data(html form), we populate the django form which validates the data . If form is valid, we just save the data in django form to the model .  Do I need to follow the same process for mongoengine also ?   If yes, how can i validate an image field.   My image field is like this :

```
 images = ListField(ImageField())
```

Also, how should I ask the user to enter a list of images in the html page that can be saved into the above field . Will provide more information if necessary

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When adding a new image to the `ListField` if you want to validate you can call `Model.validate()` to ensure its valid.

`ImageFields` take the actual image file - you can see some examples of their usage here:
https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/master/tests/test_fields.py#L1880-1968

One caveat - I havent tried an `ImageField` within a `ListField` so let me know how it goes :)